# Problems connecting to my Mac via SSH

Tags: linux, networking, macos, mac, ssh

I have Mac with remote access enabled. I can easily connect to it via SSH within local network. I have configured 22 port forwarding on my router. But I can't connect to my Mac via SSH by using router's IP address.

Here is output of ssh -v -v -v [user]@[host]:

```
ssh -v -v -v [user]@[ip]

OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011

debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config

debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *

debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 102: Applying options for *

debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0

debug1: Connecting to ip [ip] port 22.

debug1: Connection established.

debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier

debug3: Could not load "/Users/[user]/.ssh/id_rsa" as a RSA1 public key

debug1: identity file /Users/[user]/.ssh/id_rsa type 1

debug1: identity file /Users/[user]/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1

debug1: identity file /Users/[user]/.ssh/id_dsa type -1

debug1: identity file /Users/[user]/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1

debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0

debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2

debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.2

debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.2 pat OpenSSH_5*

debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK

debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "ip" from file "/Users/[user]/.ssh/known_hosts"

debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA in file /Users/[user]/.ssh/known_hosts:1

debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys

debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa

debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent

debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received

debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1

debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss

debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se

debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se

debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96

debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96

debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib

debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib

debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 

debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 

debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 

debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 

debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1

debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss

debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se

debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se

debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96

debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96

debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com

debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com

debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 

debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 

debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 

debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 

debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5

debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none

debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5

debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none

debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent

debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP

debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 140/256

debug2: bits set: 514/1024

debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent

debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY

debug1: Server host key: RSA [rsa]

debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "ip" from file "/Users/[user]/.ssh/known_hosts"

debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA in file /Users/[user]/.ssh/known_hosts:1

debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys

debug1: Host ‘ip' is known and matches the RSA host key.

debug1: Found key in /Users/[user]/.ssh/known_hosts:1

debug2: bits set: 488/1024

debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct

debug2: kex_derive_keys

debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1

debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent

debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS

debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0

debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received

debug1: Roaming not allowed by server

debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent

debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth

debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received

debug2: key: /Users/[user]/.ssh/id_rsa (0x7fe8c84182c0),

debug2: key: /Users/[user]/.ssh/id_dsa (0x0),

Connection closed by ip
```

Any hints/help?

Comment: Are you doing this from inside or outside your network? Some NAT gateways don't handle NAT loopback correctly. Have you tested yours with a simpler protocol like plain HTTP?

Comment: Yes, you are right! Figured it out by myself yesterday too by testing ssh from outside but forgot to write here.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out by myself yesterday, and Spiff is correct too. I was testing the ssh connection by using the same internet connection. Tested it from the other network and it worked.

Comment: Proper form is to either ask Spiff to provide an answer instead of just a question which you accept or provide you own, thus closing out your question.  FYI, MB.